# Implicitly Enforced Extension Method

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I've come across a case where I'm using strings left, right, and centre but having to call an extension method on them every single time to suppress commas (when I say suppress, I actually mean to wrap them in quotes as this is for CSV output).  Here's a basic example:

```
public static string CommaSuppressor(this string str)
{
    return str.Contains(',') ? string.Concat("\"", str.Replace("\"", "\"\""), "\"") : str;
}
```

Although of course there's most likely far more elegant, and efficient ways of doing this, and I probably haven't protected against edge cases which no doubt the community will make me aware of.

So for every string I ever deal with, I actually want to call this on it.  Of course with having tons of fields everywhere this means my code is littered with `myvar.CommaSuppressor()`.

Could anyone sway me in a direction where `CommaSuppressor` is implicitly called?

Comment: You seem to be missing some cases here. For example, what if the string contains no commas but does contain quotation marks?

Comment: @Eric: indeed, there could be many more cases, that one included.  These fields shouldn't even have commas in them, but alas they have found their way in.

Comment: Although admittedly I should've called the extension method something more suitable, `SuppressCommas` would've been better to "verbify" it, but actually it's not suppressing commas at all, it's just being CSV-safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure it is any better, but a different approach would be to write your own class to hold the string. In the constructor you could deal with the commas so that when you access the value they are escaped as you wish.

Comment: Actually all of the strings come out of a single object, so I could subclass the class definition of that object, cast it, then instead get the data out like that.  That way I'd never have to worry about calling my extension method at all.

Comment: Sounds good, you could either override ToString() or implement a new accessor to get a "safe" string.

Comment: Why not override the access itself.  Say, for example, the original type was `Address`, I could instead subclass it to have `SafeAddress` where `myobj.RoadName` would override the base classes `RoadName` method but instead return the safe string?

Answer (score 1):

You could create custom class with overloaded ToString() method. You could do much customization before you really get your processed string value with ToString() method. But of course, it won't be as flexible as original System.String of course

Answer (score 1):

There is no possibility to achieve this with the default string class. The only way I can think of is to create a wrapper class for `string` that calls this method every time it is needed.

Comment: This is one of the answers I expected... and hoped wouldn't be the case!

Answer (score 1):

How about only doing the comma suppression at the point where you output the string to the csv?